# celery eats up memory

Tags: django, ubuntu, docker, celery

I have a t2.medium instance on aws. Where two of my python applications and their celery workers runs inside separate docker containers. Total 4 containers are running.

For no reason, celery eats up lots of memory of instance.

[Screenshot of ps command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZVod.png)

I have checked that django is running with DEBUG_MODE False. I have configured worker_max_tasks_per_child to 200 and worker_max_memory_per_child to 200MB.

I have:

- Ubuntu Version: 16.04
- Python Version: 3.5

As of now I am not running any tasks, still it eats up instance memory. Kindly help me debugging the problem.

**Output of celery report**

software -> celery:4.0.2 (latentcall) kombu:4.0.2 py:3.5.2
            billiard:3.5.0.2 py-amqp:2.1.4

platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython

loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader

settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled

Comment: Celery version?

Comment: Celery version is 4.0.2